# How to strip <p> tags off of a javascript variable value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been building this calendar events functionality and ran into a snag. I have two files i am working with for this

1. my main calendar file which is mostly filled with jQuery and javascript, and
2. a php file which queries the mysql database for an event.

I am able to use jquery (ajax) to pull the array from the other file into my main calendar page using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p #1").load("events_array.php #3");
});     

var event_title = "<p id='1'> </p>";
```

That script then outputs the array results perfectly when I use

```
document.write(event_title);
```

However, whenever i insert the variable event_title into the title field of my calendar script it does not output the same result... instead it outputs the literal

```
<p id='1'></p>
```

See the calendar script I am inserting the variable into below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p #1").load("events_array.php #3");
});     

var event_title = "<p id='1'> </p>";

$('#example-fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: event_title,
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
```

See the 2nd to last line of the above code block: `title: event_title`. The `event_title` is a variable that I made at the beginning of the script. When i view this page now, it outputs not the variable value of 'event_title' but only the paragraph tags that were included in creating the variable.

**So how do I strip the paragraph tags off of `event_title`? All that remains is the array value from the other php file which I retrieved using the jQuery ajax script?**

Comment: why do you need the `<p>` tags in the first place? `title` is supposed to be a string and you can maniplulate the formatting using `fullCalendar` API

Answer (score 0):

The code currently passes a *string* as `event_title`, which a has nothing to do with the data you've loaded with ajax. You can use `.html()` to retrieve the loaded content instead:

```
// ... snip
events: [
    {
        title: $('#1').html(),
        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    },
```

However, if you're just using `.load()` to get the HTML to pass to fullcalendar, you should use `$.get()` instead, since there's no reason to pollute your DOM with that information:

```
$.get('events_array.php', function (html) {
    var event_title = $(html).find('#3').html();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // then fullcalendar init
        $('#example-fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: event_title,
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
            // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot for the answer. I am confused why you are saying that the variable event_title has nothing to do with the array value being passed with the ajax, since the value within event_title is the string that was passed. See my below comment: the array from the php file that the ajax is retrieving and storing in var event_title...

Comment: $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events");
    if (!$result)   { echo "Error in SELECT: " . $mysqli->error; }  else    {
        
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
               echo "<p id='3'>" . $row['title'] . "</p>";
            }
   
        }

Comment: So the "event_title" variable, is storing   $row['title'] correctly. BUT the damn <p> tags are also being stored obviously. And full calendar is only outputing the <p> tags and not outputing the $row['title'] part of the variable 'event_title'...

Comment: You specifically wrote this line: `var event_title = "<p id='1'> </p>";`. That's why I said it has nothing to do with the data fetched with ajax. Did you actually try my code?

Comment: I know thats my fault. Yes i did, the calendar no longer loads. i get this error in my browser console: 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <p id='3'>Project 3</p>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can wrap the 'event_title' in $() and call text() to it.

`$('<p>event_title here</p>').text()` will strip the html and produce `event_title here`.